# Text to columns switch text import method

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I import data from multiple sources, some comma separated and some separated with tabs. When I use the one method (text to columns based on tab separation) Excel remembers that preference and automatically uses that method the next time I import/paste data. However when I want to import data separated with the other method I have to configure the settings (now via text to columns).

Is there a way to switch method faster (with a macro triggered by a quick access button)

For now i am working with to different macro's

```
Sub T2C_tab()

Dim selectedRange As Range
Set selectedRange = Selection ' Get the selected range

selectedRange.TextToColumns _
DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
Tab:=True

End Sub

Sub T2C_comma()

Dim selectedRange As Range
Set selectedRange = Selection ' Get the selected range

selectedRange.TextToColumns _
DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
Comma:=True

End Sub
```

Working with Get & Transform isnt always the best sollution since i am also copy/pasting tables directly into my worksheets

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have tried, and explain any problems you ran into. Especially if you know the separator in advance, the macro would be pretty simple. Start by using the macro recorder. Or you could do your import using `Get & Transform` (aka `Power Query`) which seems to do a reasonable job of guessing the separator.

Comment: The VBA method Range.TextToColumns does the same thing as the text-to-columns menu option, except that you can make all parameters explicit (overruling the earlier parameters). Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns